# Personal account for wp where you can manage the purchased courses and put them on pause

Tags: javascript, php, sql, wordpress

There is a website where you can buy courses, after buying a course (30 days), the purchased course appears in your personal account, which you can manage: Put on pause for 7 days (Let's say 15 days have passed, put on pause for 7 days, and after 7 days, the courses continue for 15 days). Also, the administrator can also pause courses. How can this be implemented?

Namely, the pause of courses by the user or administrator. Maybe someone has ready-made solutions, or something similar, or at least thoughts on how it can be implemented, I will be very grateful.
Unfortunately I can't provide an example:( But if someone has a ready-made solution and you send it here, then I will be able to adapt it for myself

Comment: Without knowing the specifics of your code there isn’t a whole lot that we can tell you. Generally, I think I’d just store the “pause” as a time stamp and a duration for each user’s purchase, and when checking for expiration, sum the duration along with the original length.

Comment: _"I can't provide an example:( But if someone has a ready-made solution and you send it here"_ - 1. If you can't provide an example, there isn't much we can do. 2. This isn't a free coding service. We're here to help you sort out potential issues you run into with your existing code (which you then have to show us) and not to write it for you or to just give you code.

Answer (score 0):

You can save two dates for your `course` entity. The `startAt` date and the `endAt` date. When someone purchases a course, the purchase-date is stored in the `startAt` date field and the `endAt` date is calculated by `startAt`+`30`.
When the user then pauses a course you simply extend the `endAt` date by the pause and set a status-flag, that the course is paused.